# Автоматически узнать ширину у canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть скрипт, который формирует кнопку canvas. Внутри кнопки пишется текст,
как узнать ширину текста что бы правильно оцентровать кнопку?
Проблема такая если в canvas написать **"Буквы"** то все хорошо, а если **"Буквиница"** то символы вылезают за пределы границ.
вот код

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height  

let i = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
for(var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    let v = px(x, y)
    let o = (y*w + x)*4    
    i.data[o++] = v[0]*255
    i.data[o++] = v[1]*255
    i.data[o++] = v[2]*255
    i.data[o++] = v[3]*255
}}
c.putImageData(i, 0, 0);
c.font = "30px Arial";
c.textAlign = "center";
c.textBaseline = "middle"; 
c.fillStyle = 'hsl(250,55%,55%)' 
c.fillText(canvas.getAttribute('data-word'), w/4, h/4)

function sdRoundBox(x, y, sx, sy, r) {
  x = Math.abs(x) - sx;
  y = Math.abs(y) - sy;
  sx = Math.max(x, 0); 
  sy = Math.max(y, 0);
  return Math.min(Math.max(x, y), 0) + Math.sqrt(sx*sx + sy*sy) - r;
}

function px(x, y) {
  let d = Math.abs(sdRoundBox(4*x-w, 4*y-h, 150, 0, 100));
  if (d>16) return [0, 0, 0, 0]
  let c = Math.min(d/32 + 0.4, d/8);
  return [0.4+(x/w+1-y/h)*0.3, c, 1, 1-c];
}
```

```css
canvas{
  margin:10px
}
```

```html
<body>
<canvas width="300" height="150" id="canvas" data-word="Буквы"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо наверное сделать не так, нужно канву поставить как `border-image`

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let c = canvas.getContext('2d');
let w = canvas.width = 100;
let h = canvas.height = 50;  
let i = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
for(var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    let v = px(x, y)
    let o = (y*w + x)*4    
    i.data[o++] = v[0]*255
    i.data[o++] = v[1]*255
    i.data[o++] = v[2]*255
    i.data[o++] = v[3]*255
}}
c.putImageData(i, 0, 0);
let style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = `.example{border-image-source:url(${canvas.toDataURL()})}`;
document.head.append(style)


function sdRoundBox(x, y, sx, sy, r) {
  x = Math.abs(x) - sx;
  y = Math.abs(y) - sy;
  sx = Math.max(x, 0); 
  sy = Math.max(y, 0);
  return Math.min(Math.max(x, y), 0) + Math.sqrt(sx*sx + sy*sy) - r;
}

function px(x, y) {
  let d = Math.abs(sdRoundBox(2*x-w, 2*y-h, 45, 0, 35));
  if (d>16) return [0, 0, 0, 0]
  let c = Math.min(d/32 + 0.4, d/8);
  return [0.4+(x/w+1-y/h)*0.3, c, 1, 1-c];
}
```

```css
.example {
  border: 45px solid transparent;
  border-top:22px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:22px solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">Буквы</div>
<div class="example">БуквыБуквыБуквы</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй [`ctx.measureText()`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp). Он возвращает объект с свойством `width`, которое содержит ширину текста.